# How can I create a trigger to update a integer value to a status string in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, database-trigger

I have two tables: inspection and components. The inspection table has a column for score and a column for inspection date. The component table has a build status column which lists the status of each component based on the value of the inspection score. I need to convert the inspection score (ex. 100) to a status (ex. ready). Using a foreign key constraint, I can pull the value of the inspection score into the component build status column. However, the trigger I'm implementing is not translating that value into status. Please help:

```
    delimiter //
    create trigger build_status_update 
    before insert
    on components 
    for each row 
       begin
        update components
        set build_status = 'ready'
        where build_status >='90'; 
        update components
        set build_status = 'not-ready'
        where build_status <='75'; 
        update components
        set build_status = 'usable'
        where build_status = null; 
     end
     //
     delimiter ;
```

Comment: Are you able to post the table structure for the 2 tables. From your description, I think your overall thinking may be flawed and the solution you are looking for is different from the answer to this question.

Comment: Table 1: Inspection, Columns = Date, Component_Numb, Score; Table 2: Components, Columns = Component_Name, Component_Numb, Build_Status

Comment: What I'm trying to do: if the inspection.score is >= to '90' then the component.build_status = 'ready' etc.

Answer (score 0):

From your comment, I think your table structure is something like this:

```
tbl_Inspection:
-------------------------------------------
id int not null
date datetime
score int
component_id int (foreign key to component)

tbl_component
-------------------------------------------
id int not null
name varchar(255)
build_status <==== should default to "not-ready"
```

Now, here is the obvious problem - how is there an inspection before a component? Your trigger as set for ON INSERT into the component table. But, since an inspection references a component, there can't be an inspection before the component.

If, on the other hand your trigger is setup on the inspection table, it becomes somewhat easier. The following code is based on score >= 90 the component is ready, otherwise it is not ready.

```
delimiter //
create trigger build_status_update 
before insert
on inspections 
for each row 
   begin
    update components
       set build_status = if(new.score>=90,'ready','not-ready')
       where id = new.component_id; 
   end
 //
 delimiter ;
```

This has the trigger updating a corresponding record in the components table when inserting a record into the inspections table.

Comment: You're welcome - if that solved your problem, you can accept this as the correct answer